# Can't use context menu 2.81

Tags: 3d-view

When I add a new object and I want to change the properties of it I can't change any of the options in the context menu. The options look grayed out and when I click I just click through the window into the 3D viewport.

This only happens when adding meshes: When I go into edit mode and bevel, then pop up the context menu I can change values just fine.

To clarify, I have used 2.81 full time for a couple of days now with no issues, one second it was fine the next I couldn't use it anymore, I'm pretty sure that means it must have been a thing on my end.

Restarting blender and making a new project doesn't work.

I've been using Blender since 2.69 and never had anything occur similar to this.

[image: Click-through context menu]

Comment: Hello :). Seems like a bug, but if you'll share your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: @JachymMichal uploaded an empty blender file because the file the issue first occurred in is sadly one I cannot share, the issue occurs over multiple projects though. Hopefully it can be of use. :)
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6910" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6910/)

Comment: Hello again :). It works just fine for me, so it might be your Preferences messed up.  Try to reset them to Factory preferences, that should narrow it down.

Comment: I wonder if you changed your mouse to right click select? If you did and put it back to left click, you might see it normally.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to, but that fixed it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Factory reset my preferences fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear that, I'll know what to do when this happens to me :). You can now mark your question as solved, for other poor souls that encounter this.

Comment: I have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer :/